# How to modify window contents based on QComboBox value

Tags: qt, qcombobox, qlabel, qlineedit

I have a Qt window which contains a QComboBox and a few QLabels and QLineEdits.  Based on the QComboBox value that the user chooses, I would like to dynamically change the QLabels and QLineEdits in the window while it is still open.

For example, if the QComboBox has a list of countries, and the user chooses France, I would like to change all the QLabels and QLineEdits into French; the user is then expected to fill out the QLineEdits in French before clicking on the Save/Close button at the bottom.

Can this be done in Qt?

Comment: It can be done easily. Connect `QComboBox::activated` to a slot which tests for the user's choice and calls `QLabel::setText` and `QLineEdit::setText` accordingly.

Comment: do you mean to translate the contents of QLabel and QLineEdit at runtime?

Comment: Have a look into your `ui_XXX.h` files, you'll find a function named `retranslateUi(QWidget *...)`. That should give you a hint how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are only looking for language translating, there are other ways to do that in Qt where you can use dictionaries to translate Ui text.  Take a look at https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtlinguist-hellotr-example.html

But it sounds like your question is not meant to be only about language, so to do this you can use the QComboBox signal currentTextChanged, and a slot that will receive the current value and update labels based on that text.  Alternately if you do not want to use a bunch of ifs you could use the signal currentIndexChanged and use a switch.

In my ui file I have (4) objects: a comboBox and label1 through 3.

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    ui->comboBox->addItem("Selected Option 1");
    ui->comboBox->addItem("Selected Option 2");
    ui->comboBox->addItem("Selected Option 3");


    connect(ui->comboBox, &QComboBox::currentTextChanged,
            this,   &MainWindow::setLabelText);

}

void MainWindow::setLabelText(const QString comboText)
{
    if(comboText == "Selected Option 1")
    {
        ui->label1->setText("Text when option 1 is selected");
        ui->label2->setText("Text when option 1 is selected");
        ui->label3->setText("Text when option 1 is selected");
    }
    else if(comboText == "Selected Option 2")
    {
        ui->label1->setText("Text when option 2 is selected");
        ui->label2->setText("Text when option 2 is selected");
        ui->label3->setText("Text when option 2 is selected");
    }
    else if(comboText == "Selected Option 3")
    {
        ui->label1->setText("Text when option 3 is selected");
        ui->label2->setText("Text when option 3 is selected");
        ui->label3->setText("Text when option 3 is selected");
    }
}
```

In your header make sure you define setLabeText as a **slot**.

```
private slots:
    void setLabelText(const QString comboText);
```